# solr 4.10で 異なるcore間のデータをjoinして要素を取得する方法は？

Tags: java, solr

solr 4.10で下記のsqlのようなJOINして各core内の要素を取得する方法がわからずハマっております。

```
SELECT
 child.*,parent.*
FROM child 
JOIN parent
WHERE child.parent_id=parent.id AND parent.tag='hoge'`
```

childとparentは多対一の関係でparentが複数になることはありません。
下記の通り試したところ、WHERE句は問題なく指定できましたがSELECT句でparentの要素を取ることができない状態です。

```
select?q={!join from=parent_id to=id fromIndex=parent}id:1+tag:hoge
```

自分で調べた感じでは無理なのではという気もしておりますが、ご教示のほどよろしくお願いします。